# What are the best chart/graph js plugins?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I'm trying to find a smart way to display data on my dashboard page. What are the nicest and most flexible resources to plot charts and graphs?

Comment: [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) look quite good. Never used it though

Comment: At least "nicest" is quite subjective. I suggest to search for some libraries/services with your favorite search engine, have a look at them and then decide for yourself.

Comment: You are perfectly right, and prior to any subjective criterion I'm looking for the most performant and flexible solution. 'Nice' may overlap these notions but is misleading though. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First determine if you want to use an hosted solution like google charts, or you want more control and need a library you want to host yourself. Hosted solutions are very convenient and integrate fairly quickly, but your data is inherently exposed to the outside world. If you're building a corporate site this can be a "no go".

Also think if you want a client side or server side solution. I personally would go for a client side library if you don't have a huge amount of data that needs to be visualized. Client side libraries very often are more flexible (think: animation, resizing, etc)

I have used [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). It is very powerful, and has many types of graphs, but it can be hard to find the setting that you need to get the exact effect that you want. Not because the documentation is bad (which it isn't), but because there are so many options.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)?

Comment: Sure I did consider Google Charts, but I'm curious to see if there are interesting open source alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Visualize](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/). I like it, because it's fully accessible :).